# MyClass as @PathParam in Jersey resource method

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In my Jersey resource i have:

```
@GET
@Path("/{dataType}/{dataSet}")
public Response search(
        @PathParam("dataType") String dataType,
        @PathParam("dataSet") String dataSet){
    ...
}
```

Instead of strings i want to use my own classes:

```
@GET
@Path("/{dataType}/{dataSet}")
public Response search(
        @PathParam("dataType") DataType dataType,
        @PathParam("dataSet") DataSet dataSet){
    ...
}
```

However DataSet is dependent on DataType(DataSet uses DataType in it's constructor). Is there a way to do this with Jersey?

Comment: I'm not clear how DataType and DataSet are related.  Can you paste some of the source to those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use Jersey's built-in transformation using a static `fromString()` method (see the [Jersey documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e260)), or use a custom provider to handle the path segments.  For the latter, you will need a class something like this:

```
public class MyProvider extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<Context, DataType> {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

    public Injectable<DataType> getInjectable(ComponentContext componentCtx, Context ctx) {
        uri.getPathSegments();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Because i need DataType to create DataSet i can't use `fromString` method. Provider works fine for me. I can use path segments for both and create what i need. I wonder is there a better way to do this? Specifically i was looking into a way to create two resources. One for DataType which from it's method returns other resource which in turns returns what i need. In this case i will need to inject first resource into my provider for second resource path parameter. Does this sounds like something worth to be done, or do you think it will be better just to stay with single resource?

Comment: Hm, I'm not too sure, but have you tried looking at Jersey subresources?

Comment: @efan If you have more information, I'd be great if you could post it for others.